# Android: Having trouble getting html from webpage

Tags: php, android, html, request

I'm writing an android application that is supposed to get the html from a php page and use the parsed data from thepage.  I've searched for this issue on here, and ended up using some code from an example another poster put up.  Here is my code so far:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        Log.d("first","first");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        String html = "";
        Log.d("second","second");
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        Log.d("third","third");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        Log.d("fourth","fourth");
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        Log.d("fifth","fifth");
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("request line",line);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("error", "error");
    }
    Log.d("end","end");
}
```

Like I said before, the url is a php page.  Whenever I run this code, it prints out the first first message, but then prints out the error error message and then finally the end end message.  I've tried modifying the headers, but I've had no luck with it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

When I do e.getMessage() and print that out, in the logger all it says is stanford.edu.  Hope that helps.  Here is the stack trace:

01-17 16:58:27.687: WARN/System.err(452): java.net.UnknownHostException: stanford.edu
01-17 16:58:27.947: WARN/System.err(452):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
01-17 16:58:27.947: WARN/System.err(452):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
01-17 16:58:27.977: WARN/System.err(452):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
01-17 16:58:27.977: WARN/System.err(452):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
01-17 16:58:28.027: WARN/System.err(452):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-17 16:58:28.027: WARN/System.err(452):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-17 16:58:28.047: WARN/System.err(452):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
01-17 16:58:28.057: WARN/System.err(452):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-17 16:58:28.057: WARN/System.err(452):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-17 16:58:28.117: WARN/System.err(452):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-17 16:58:28.117: WARN/System.err(452):     at edu.stanford.cs247.util.ColorHandler.getInfo(ColorHandler.java:44)
01-17 16:58:28.217: WARN/System.err(452):     at edu.stanford.cs247.util.ColorHandler.handleMessage(ColorHandler.java:70)
01-17 16:58:28.217: WARN/System.err(452):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 16:58:28.247: WARN/System.err(452):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-17 16:58:28.257: WARN/System.err(452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
01-17 16:58:28.257: WARN/System.err(452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 16:58:28.297: WARN/System.err(452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-17 16:58:28.297: WARN/System.err(452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-17 16:58:28.327: WARN/System.err(452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-17 16:58:28.337: WARN/System.err(452):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the internet permission in my manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `Log.d()` method calls may be something like `Log.d("MyAppName", "Message")` not `Log.d("Message", "Message")` In this way you can create a filter in LogCat for your app and see only your messages. (Check this on Eclipse)

For your problem, try putting some useful message in the catch block, something like:

```
try{
...
} catch (IOException e){
Log.d("MyAppName", e.getMessage());
}
```

This will show you the problem that throw the exception.
Consider take a look to [this](http://code.google.com/p/wiktionary-android/source/browse/trunk/SimpleWiktionary/src/com/example/android/simplewiktionary/SimpleWikiHelper.java) sample code, the `getUrlContent()` do exactly what you wont.

Good luck

Comment: @GojaN Log.d("MyClass", "MyMessage", e); would probably be preferable.  That way you get the full stacktrace.

Comment: That's a god one. Maybe i prefer Log.d("MyClass", e.getMessage(), e). This way you have a combination of both :)

Comment: When I printed out the message, all it said was my university's name.edu

Comment: @GojaN actually, when you ask it to print the stacktrace that includes the message text.

Comment: @Kyle  Did you print out the full stacktrace?  Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: Just posted it.  Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your stacktrace says:

> java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   stanford.edu

You should learn to read stacktraces.  A quick search for "UnknownHostException" tells you it is:

> Thrown to indicate that the IP address
>   of a host could not be determined.

This means that it can't turn stanford.edu into an IP.  You probably need `www.stanford.edu` or something like that.  Try pinging the address on the command line `ping www.stanford.edu` , and make sure it resolves to an ip address.

Comment: I did that before to no avail :(

Comment: I know how to read stack traces, I just couldn't find anything that would help me when I looked up UnknownHostException :(

Comment: It's resolving to an ip address

Comment: figured it out.  I didn't add the internet permission to my manifest file :(

Answer (score 0):

add to Manifest 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`